# How can I receive the data of my List sent through a method POST in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, list, spring-boot

I am making a REST api in Java with Spring boot JPA Hibernate and with H2 database, I am trying to do a POST to "api/facturas" which is the RequestMapping of FacturaController, in which I want to add data to the FacturaDetalles List, but It returns an empty array, as if the data had never been sent, what am I doing wrong here?

**I am trying to make a POST to "*/api/facturas*" like this:**

```
{
     "cliente": {
         "idCliente": 1
     },
     "facturaDetalles": [
         {
             "producto": {
                 "idProducto": 3
             }
         }
     ]
}
```

**This is what it should return:**

```
{
        "cliente": {
            "idCliente": 1,
            "nombreCliente": "Juan",
            "apellidoCliente": "Rufiol",
            "dni": 35884121,
            "direccionCliente": "Av. Siempre Viva 300",
            "telefonoCliente": 353654128,
            "emailCliente": "juancito@gmail.com",
            "cuit": 5412456985510,
            "ciudad": "Capital Federal",
            "provincia": "Buenos Aires",
            "pais": "Argentina",
            "codigoPostal": 1426,
            "fechaNacimiento": "10-10-1980"
        },
        "facturaDetalles": [
            {
                "idFacturaDetalles": 1,
                "producto": {
                    "idProducto": 3,
                    "nombreProducto": "Pollo frito",
                    "precioProducto": 40,
                    "descripcion": "Una delicia king chicken",
                    "stock": 3
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

**This is what i get:**

```
{
        "cliente": {
            "idCliente": 1,
            "nombreCliente": "Juan",
            "apellidoCliente": "Rufiol",
            "dni": 35884121,
            "direccionCliente": "Av. Siempre Viva 300",
            "telefonoCliente": 353654128,
            "emailCliente": "juancito@gmail.com",
            "cuit": 5412456985510,
            "ciudad": "Capital Federal",
            "provincia": "Buenos Aires",
            "pais": "Argentina",
            "codigoPostal": 1426,
            "fechaNacimiento": "10-10-1980"
        },
        "facturaDetalles": []
    }
```

[data.sql]

```
INSERT INTO clientes (nombre,apellido,dni,direccion,telefono,email,cuit,ciudad,provincia,pais,codigo_postal, fecha_nacimiento ) VALUES ('Juan','Rufiol','35884121','Av. Siempre Viva 300','353654128','juancito@gmail.com','5412456985510','Capital Federal','Buenos Aires', 'Argentina',1426,'10-10-1980'  );
INSERT INTO clientes (nombre,apellido,dni,direccion,telefono,email,cuit,ciudad,provincia,pais,codigo_postal, fecha_nacimiento ) VALUES ('Rolo','Garcia','41882121','Mariano Moreno 44','353614128','rolaso@rol.com','51134569854113','Capital Federal','Buenos Aires', 'Argentina',1426,'01-03-1989' );

INSERT INTO facturas (nro_factura,tipo_factura,precio_total_factura,id_cliente) VALUES (4444,'A',2000,1);
INSERT INTO facturas (nro_factura,tipo_factura,precio_total_factura,id_cliente ) VALUES (4444,'A',2000,1);

INSERT INTO facturas_detalles (cantidad,subtotal,id_facturas ,id_producto) VALUES (1,1,1,3);
INSERT INTO facturas_detalles (cantidad,subtotal,id_facturas ,id_producto) VALUES (1,1,1,2);
```

[Factura]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "facturas")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Factura {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long idFactura;

    @Column(name = "nro_factura")
    private Integer nroFactura;

    @Column(name = "tipo_factura")
    private String tipoFactura;

    @Column(name = "fecha", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private String fechaFactura;


    @Column(name = "precio_total_factura")
    private Integer precioTotalFactura;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;


    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "factura", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FacturaDetalles> facturaDetalles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_empresa")
    private Empresa empresa;


}
```

[FacturaDTO]

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FacturaDTO {
    
    private ClienteDTO cliente;
    private List<FacturaDetallesDTO> facturaDetalles;
}
```

[FacturaServiceImp]

```
@Service
public class FacturaServiceImp implements FacturaService {

    @Autowired
    private FacturaRepository facturaRepository;


    public List<Factura> getAllFacturas() {
        return facturaRepository.findAll();

    }

    public Factura getOneFactura(Long id) {
        return facturaRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Factura no encontrado"));
    }


    public Factura createFactura(Factura factura) {
        return facturaRepository.save(factura);
    }


    public void deleteFactura(Long id) {
        facturaRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

[FacturaService]

```
 public interface FacturaService {

    List<Factura> getAllFacturas();

    Factura getOneFactura(Long id);

    Factura createFactura(Factura factura);

    void deleteFactura(Long id);


}
```

[FacturaController]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/facturas")
public class FacturaController {

    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    FacturaService facturaService;


    @GetMapping()
    public List<FacturaDTO> getAllFacturas() {
        return facturaService.getAllFacturas().stream().map(factura -> modelMapper.map(factura, FacturaDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
 

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<FacturaDTO> getOneFactura(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Factura factura = facturaService.getOneFactura(id);
        FacturaDTO facturaDTO = modelMapper.map(factura, FacturaDTO.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(facturaDTO);

    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<FacturaDTO> createFactura(@RequestBody FacturaDTO facturaDTO) {
        Factura factura = modelMapper.map(facturaDTO, Factura.class);
        Factura facturaCreacion = facturaService.createFactura(factura);
        FacturaDTO conversion = modelMapper.map(facturaCreacion, FacturaDTO.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<FacturaDTO>(conversion, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }


    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<FacturaDTO> deleteFactura(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Factura factura = facturaService.getOneFactura(id);
        facturaService.deleteFactura(id);
        FacturaDTO facturaDTO = modelMapper.map(factura, FacturaDTO.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(facturaDTO);
    }


}
```

[FacturaDetalles]

```
@Entity(name = "facturas_detalles")
@Table(name = "facturas_detalles")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FacturaDetalles {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long idFacturaDetalles;

    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private Integer cantidadProductos;

    @Column(name = "subtotal")
    private Integer totalParcial;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_facturas")
    private Factura factura;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_producto")
    private Producto producto;
}
```

[FacturaDetallesDTO]

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FacturaDetallesDTO {

    private Long idFacturaDetalles;
    private ProductoDTO producto;

}
```

[FacturaDetallesServiceImp]

```
@Service
public class FacturaDetallesServiceImp implements FacturaDetallesService {

    @Autowired
    private FacturaDetallesRepository facturaDetallesRepository;


    public List<FacturaDetalles> getAllFacturaDetalles() {
        return facturaDetallesRepository.findAll();
    }

    public FacturaDetalles getOneFacturaDetalles(Long id) {
        return facturaDetallesRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Factura no encontrado"));
    }

    public FacturaDetalles createFacturaDetalles(FacturaDetalles facturaDetalles) {
        return facturaDetallesRepository.save(facturaDetalles);
     }

    public void deleteFacturaDetalles(Long id) {
        facturaDetallesRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

[FacturaDetallesService]

```
public interface FacturaDetallesService {
    
    List<FacturaDetalles> getAllFacturaDetalles();
    FacturaDetalles getOneFacturaDetalles(Long id);
    void deleteFacturaDetalles(Long id);
    FacturaDetalles createFacturaDetalles(FacturaDetalles facturaDetalles);

}
```

[FacturaDetallesController]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/detalles")
public class FacturaDetallesController {

    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
      FacturaDetallesService facturaDetallesService;


    @GetMapping()
    public List<FacturaDetallesDTO> getAllFacturaDetalles() {
        return facturaDetallesService.getAllFacturaDetalles().stream().map(facturaDetalles -> modelMapper.map(facturaDetalles, FacturaDetallesDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<FacturaDetallesDTO> getOneFacturaDetalles(@PathVariable Long id) {
        FacturaDetalles facturaDetalles = facturaDetallesService.getOneFacturaDetalles(id);
        FacturaDetallesDTO detallesDTO = modelMapper.map(facturaDetalles, FacturaDetallesDTO.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(detallesDTO);
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<FacturaDetallesDTO> createFacturaDetalles(@RequestBody FacturaDetallesDTO facturaDetallesDTO) {
           FacturaDetalles facturaDetalles = modelMapper.map(facturaDetallesDTO, FacturaDetalles.class);
            FacturaDetalles facturaDetallesCreacion = facturaDetallesService.createFacturaDetalles(facturaDetalles);
            FacturaDetallesDTO conversion = modelMapper.map(facturaDetallesCreacion, FacturaDetallesDTO.class);
            return new ResponseEntity<FacturaDetallesDTO>(conversion, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<FacturaDetallesDTO> deleteFacturaDetalles(@PathVariable Long id){
        FacturaDetalles facturaDetalles = facturaDetallesService.getOneFacturaDetalles(id);
        facturaDetallesService.deleteFacturaDetalles(id);
        FacturaDetallesDTO detallesDTO = modelMapper.map(facturaDetalles, FacturaDetallesDTO.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(detallesDTO);
    }


}
```

Comment: what's going on here? `Factura factura = modelMapper.map(facturaDTO, Factura.class);` Is there a db query inside which gets the existing factura by id from dto?

Comment: No Marc, ModelMapper is what I am using to map the entities and DTOS

Comment: Thanks for your help! How could I obtain the existing factura by id from dto?

Answer (score 1):

try like this (lines omitted due to readability, e.g. checks)

```
@Autowired
private FacturaRepository facturaRepository;

@Autowired
private FacturaDetallesRepository facturaDetallesRepository;


public Factura createFactura(...) {

    // get factura from db (by id from dto)
    Factura factura = facturaRepository.findByIdFactura(facura.getIdFactura())

    // get facturaDetalles from db (by id from dto)
    FacturaDetalles facturaDetalles = facturaDetallesRepository.findByIdFacturaDetalles(...)

    // link entites, for each detalles object!
    facturaDetalles.setFactura(factura)

    // add to list, but check if already in list first
    factura.getFacturaDetalles().add(facturaDetalles)

    facturaRepository.save(factura);
}
```